# LWC: How to track wired properties' LDS activity

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-data-service

As I have written more LWC components, I've generally found that things work best when you stick with the reactive model as much as possible, and that by properly writing your getters to gracefully handle not-yet-ready data, it's possible (and better) to wire most `Cachable` Apex to properties instead of functions.  For example:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getInitialData from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.getInitialData';

export default class ComponentExample extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getInitialData, {recordId: '$recordId}) initialDataResponse;

    get recordData() {
        return this.initialDataResponse?.data;
    }

    get errorMessage() {
        return this.initialDataResponse?.error?.body.message;
    }

    get hasError() {
        return !!this.initialDataResponse?.error;
    }}

    // etc...

}
```

As I've gotten used to this style, I've found that I almost never need to wire an apex method to a JS function.  Where I'm having an issue is long-running methods, where I'd like to show a spinner while the data is fetched.  In the simplest case of loading data when the component loads, I've done something like this:

```
export default class ComponentExample extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    showSpinner = true;
    initialDataResponse;

    @wire(getInitialData, {recordId: '$recordId}) wiredResponse(initialDataResponse) {
        this.initialDataResponse = initialDataResponse;
        this.showSpinner = false;
    }
```

This works, but only at load time, and it requires wiring a function.  If a dynamic parameter changes (`recordId` in the example), I have no way to set `showSpinner = true` before LDS calls Apex, as the wired function is only called when the apex call completes.

What I'd really like is to receive an event whenever LDS calls the wired method to re-provision the data, and an event when the fetch is complete, so that I can manage my spinner accordingly.  And while in some cases I can simply derive a "showSpinner" value from the data in the page, I often use a hierarchy of components, where I'd like subcomponents to fire a `server` event with a `start` or `stop` payload, and let the parent component manage the spinner at the parent level.  I can find no way to fire events when a computed value (getter) changes.

I haven't found any way to achieve this level of granularity with LDS.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

adding this as an FYI as this is an old question without any responses.. this is what I've done in the past to get around this issue as I've also had the same sort of problems arise.

I have added a private variable for record id and used a setter to change the spinner, takes a little playing around but eh... so as an example to make your example a little cleaner:

```
_recordId;
@api 
get recordId(){
    return _recordId;
};

set recordId(value){
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this._recordId = value;
}
```